# How to runtime generate div through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

While doing example of JSON, I found that values are overwritten. I want to generate a div for each value but how?

Javascript code:

```
<script>
var txt = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","nationality":"Pakistani","Age":"24","Salary":"40000" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith","nationality":"USA","Age":"24","Salary":"40000" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones","nationality":"UK","Age":"24","Salary":"40000" }]}';

window.onload = function(){
for(var i = 0 ; i< 3 ; i++){
var obj = eval ("("+ txt +")");
document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].firstName;
document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].lastName;
document.getElementById("nationality").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].nationality;
document.getElementById("Age").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].Age;
document.getElementById("Salary").innerHTML=obj.employees[i].Salary;}
}
</script>
```

Html body:

```
<div>
<p>
First Name: <span id="fname"></span><br /> 
Last Name: <span id="lname"></span><br /> 
Nationality: <span id="nationality"></span><br />
Age: <span id="Age"></span><br />
Salary: <span id="Salary"></span><br />
</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at `createElement`. At the moment, you're looping through all the values and assigning them to the same span, so each time it goes through the loop then the values get overwritten.

Comment: This isn't directly related, but as a tip - you can use `JSON.parse()` on your json data instead of eval.  I'd also suggest doing that outside of your loop, to gain some runtime efficiency (in a case like this, there will be no perceived distance - but still good practice).

Comment: @NickR, I think createElement will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is typically done through templates. You should look into the new HTML5 `template` element, which makes the work of templating your data super easy.

*Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template*

In your case, just `JSON.parse` the string to obtain the object array from the text, and then loop through it. With each iteration, clone (copy) the template into an element, replace the fields using an appropriate query selector and append to the document.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/VNtdU/1/***

Relevant HTML:

```
<template id="mytemplate">
    <div>
        <p>
            First Name: <span class="fname"></span><br />
            Last Name: <span class="lname"></span><br />
    ...
</template>
```

*Relevant Javascript*:

```
var list = JSON.parse(txt);
list.employees.forEach(function(obj) {
    var template = document.getElementById('mytemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    template.querySelector('.fname').innerText = obj.firstName;
    template.querySelector('.lname').innerText = obj.lastName;
    template.querySelector('.nationality').innerText = obj.nationality;
    template.querySelector('.age').innerText = obj.Age;
    template.querySelector('.salary').innerText = obj.Salary;
    document.body.appendChild(template);
});
```

*Where*:

1. `txt` is the your json string (same as in your question)
2. It's preferable to use classes instead of `id`, otherwise your `id` gets duplicated and will no longer be unique.
3. You could also use `document.importNode` alternatively to `content.cloneNode`
4. The `true` parameter to `cloneNode` or `importNode` means *deep* copy, indicating whether the descendants of the imported node need to be imported.

*Important*:

`template` is an HTML5 addition (candidate recommendation) and currently is not supported in IE. Support in Safari is also flaky. Hence, use it carefully.

You may check the support at runtime by:

```
if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {...
```

*Aside*:

Mostly, `script` element is also used in the similar way as above:

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">...
```